# Regular Expression - inserting space after comma only if succeeded by a letter or number

Tags: java, regex

In Java I want to insert a space after a String but only if the character after the comma is succeeded by a digit or letter.    I am hoping to use the replaceAll method which uses regular expressions as a parameter.  So far I have the following:

```
String s1="428.0,chf";
s1 = s1.replaceAll(",(\\d|\\w)",", ");
```

This code does successfully distinguish between the String above and one where there is already a space after the comma.   My problem is that I can't figure out how to write the expression so that the space is inserted.   The code above will replace the c in the String shown above with a space.    This is not what I want.

`s1` should look like this after executing the `replaceAll`: `"428.0 chf"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and note that `$1` refers to your matched grouping:

```
s1.replaceAll(",(\\d|\\w)"," $1");
```

Note that `String.replaceAll()` works in the same way as a `Matcher.replaceAll()`. From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29):

> The replacement string may contain references to captured subsequences

Answer (score 4):

```
s1.replaceAll(",(?=[\da-zA-Z])"," ");
```

`(?=[\da-zA-Z])` is a `positive lookahead` which would look for a digit or a word after `,`.This lookahead would not be replaced since it is never included in the result.It's just a **check**

**NOTE**

`\w` includes digit,alphabets and a `_`.So no need of `\d`.

A better way to represent it would be `[\da-zA-Z]` instead of `\w` since `\w` also includes `_` which you do not need 2 match

Answer (score 2):

```
String s1="428.0,chf";
s1 = s1.replaceAll(",([^_]\\w)"," $1"); //Match alphanumeric except '_' after ','
System.out.println(s1);
```

**Output: -**

```
428.0 chf
```

Since `\w` matches `digits`, `words,` and an `underscore`, So, `[^_]` negates the `underscore` from `\w`..

**`$1`** represents the captured group.. You captured `c` after `,` here, so replace `c` with `_$1` -> `_c`..  "_" represent a space..

Comment: This doesn't do precisely what he wants, I don't think. Note the comma

Comment: @BrianAgnew.. Thanks :) .. Actually OP's content and Title doesn't match.. So I got it wrong the first time. Edited the code..

Comment: `\w` includes a `\d`..no need of `\d` then..be aware of `_ `though

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
public class Tes {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String s1="428.0,chf";

        String[] sArr = s1.split(",");

        String finalStr = new String();

        for(String s : sArr){

            finalStr = finalStr +" "+ s;
        }

        System.out.println(finalStr);

    }

}
```

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra.. This doesn't check the condition whether the next character is a letter or number..